# The coset corresponding to permutation $(123)$ in $\Bbb Z /3\Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

We know that  $V_4 \triangleleft A_4$ so $ A_4/V_4 \cong \Bbb Z /3\Bbb Z$.

The coset corresponding to permutation $(123)$ is $(123)V_4$. Is it corresponding to $\overline{1}$ or $\overline{2}$ in $\Bbb Z /3\Bbb Z$?

Both  $\overline{1}$ and  $\overline{2}$ are of order 3 so I don't see if there is a canonical morphism $ A_4/V_4 \cong \Bbb Z /3\Bbb Z$ or just a matter of choice?

Thank you for your help.

### Edit

Let's fix $j=e^{2i\pi/3}$.

Let $(\Bbb C^*, \rho)$ be a 1-dim representation of $A_4$ and let $\pi: A_4\to A_4/V_4$ and $\rho': A_4/V_4\to \Bbb C^*$ so we have $\chi_{\omega}(g)=\rho(g)=\rho'\circ\pi(g)$ for $g\in A_4$.

We know that $\rho'(\overline{k}) = \omega^k$ where $\omega$ is $3$-th root of unity.

If we choose $\pi((123)) = \overline{1}$ then we should have $\omega = j\Rightarrow \chi_j((123))=j, \chi_{j^2}((123))=j^2$

If we choose $\pi((123)) = \overline{2}$ then we should have $\omega = j^2\Rightarrow \chi_j((123))=j^2, \chi_{j^2}((123))=j$ and we don't preserve the character table of $A_4$:

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A_4& id & (12)(34) & (123) & (132)\\ \hline
 \chi_{id}&1 &1 &1 & 1\\ \hline
 \chi_{j}& 1 &1 &j & j^2\\ \hline
 \chi_{j^2}&1 & 1& j^2 & j\\ \hline.
\end{array}$

I don't understand why $\omega$ depends on the choice of $\pi((132))$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a matter of choice: $x\mapsto - x$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb Z_3 /3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: wouldn't this cause an issue in the representation table of $A_4$? the columns corresponding to the conjugacy classes of $(123)$ and $(132)$ would be interchangeable for dimension 1 representations?

Comment: Lining up the relevant representations of $A_4$ with the representations of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ **depends** on the choice of isomorphism $A_4/V_4\to \mathbb{Z}_3$, not the other way around.

Comment: @DavidHill Then if I choose to assign $(132)V4$ coset to $\overline{1}\in \mathbb{Z}_3$, would the character table of $A_4$ still be correct?

Comment: The character table does not depend on this assignment. If you assign $(132)V_4$ to $\bar{1}$, then the $1$-d rep of $A_4$ where $V_4$ acts as $1$ and $(123)$ acts as $e^{2\pi i/3}$ corresponds to the representation of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ where $\bar{1}$ acts by $e^{4\pi i/3}$.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHill, I am still not clear on my question, please check my edit

Comment: If you switch the last two columns, then switch the last two displayed rows, you end up with the same table. Which is the same as saying that if you switch the isomorphism, then you switch the corresponding representations.